# Error while ordering a table

Tags: r

I have an issue with ordering a table in **R**.
I have this table here:

```
    Date    Race    time    Fav Odds        win place   joint
01/04/2013  Redcar  14:30   4   1   n   y   j
01/04/2013  Redcar  15:00   9   4   n   y   
01/04/2013  Redcar  15:30   7   4   n   y   
01/04/2013  Redcar  16:00   11  4   y       j
01/04/2013  Redcar  16:30   9   4   n   y   
01/04/2013  Redcar  17:00   7   2   n   n   
01/04/2013  Redcar  17:30   6   4   n   n   
01/04/2013  Warwick 14:20   8   13  y       
01/04/2013  Warwick 14:50   9   2   y       j
01/04/2013  Warwick 15:20   6   4   y       
01/04/2013  Warwick 15:50   7   4   n   n   
01/04/2013  Warwick 16:20   7   4   n   n   
01/04/2013  Warwick 16:50   11  8   n   n   
01/04/2013  Yarmouth 14:05  10  11  n   n   
01/04/2013  Yarmouth 14:40  5   2   y       j
01/04/2013  Yarmouth 15:10  10  3   n   n   
01/04/2013  Yarmouth 15:40  7   2   n   n   
01/04/2013  Yarmouth 16:10  2   1   n   n   
01/04/2013  Yarmouth 16:40  11  10  n   y   
01/04/2013  Yarmouth 17:10  7   2   n   n   
02/04/2013  Kempton 14:00   7   2   y       
02/04/2013  Kempton 14:30   13  8   n   y   
02/04/2013  Kempton 15:00   7   4   n   y   
02/04/2013  Kempton 15:30   10  11  y       
02/04/2013  Kempton 16:00   2   1   n   y   
02/04/2013  Kempton 16:30   4   1   n   n   
02/04/2013  Kempton 17:00   11  4   n   y   
02/04/2013  Southwell 14:20 1   2   y       
02/04/2013  Southwell 14:50 11  8   y       
02/04/2013  Southwell 15:20 2   1   n   y   
02/04/2013  Southwell 15:50 7   2   n   y   j
02/04/2013  Southwell 16:20 8   13  y       
02/04/2013  Southwell 16:50 9   4   n       
02/04/2013  Southwell 17:20 13  8   n   n   
03/04/2013  Dundalk 18:20   7   2   y       
03/04/2013  Dundalk 18:50   11  8   n   n   
03/04/2013  Dundalk 19:20   3   1   n   y   
03/04/2013  Dundalk 19:50   11  4   n   n   
03/04/2013  Dundalk 20:20   6   4   n   y   
03/04/2013  Dundalk 20:50   1   5   n   y   
03/04/2013  Dundalk 21:20   13  8   n   y   
03/04/2013  Kempton 17:30   11  8   n   n   
03/04/2013  Kempton 18:00   7   4   y       j
03/04/2013  Kempton 18:30   8   11  n   y   
03/04/2013  Kempton 19:00   1   2   n   y   
03/04/2013  Kempton 19:30   5   2   n   y   
03/04/2013  Kempton 20:00   2   1   y       
03/04/2013  Kempton 20:30   4   5   n   y   
03/04/2013  Lingfield 14:00 4   5   n   n   
03/04/2013  Lingfield 14:30 4   7   y       
03/04/2013  Lingfield 15:00 6   4   y       
03/04/2013  Lingfield 15:30 3   1   n   y   
03/04/2013  Lingfield 16:00 2   1   n   y   
03/04/2013  Lingfield 16:30 4   6   n   n   
03/04/2013  Lingfield 17:00 6   4   y       
03/04/2013  Southwell 14:20 6   4   y       
03/04/2013  Southwell 14:50 7   4   n   n   
03/04/2013  Southwell 15:20 1   4   y       
03/04/2013  Southwell 15:50 10  11  n   n   
03/04/2013  Southwell 16:20 4   7   n   n   
03/04/2013  Southwell 16:50 13  8   y       
03/04/2013  Southwell 17:20 5   2   y       
04/04/2013  Lingfield 14:20 11  4   y       
04/04/2013  Lingfield 14:55 4   6   y       
04/04/2013  Lingfield 15:30 9   4   y       
04/04/2013  Lingfield 16:05 11  4   n   y   
04/04/2013  Lingfield 16:40 6   4   n   y   
04/04/2013  Lingfield 17:15 7   4   y       
04/04/2013  Lingfield 17:45 6   4   n   n
```

I need to sort it inside **R** by hour in ascending order, and sort the other columns respectively. I tried doing this by first assigning it to a variable called `table`:

```
table <- read.csv("assessment.csv")
```

Afterwards, when I try to store that table into a new table called `sortedTable` like that:

```
sortedTable <- table[order(time),]
```

I get this error:

> Error in order(time) : argument 1 is not a vector

I managed to do this once, I don't know how, but even then, the table was sorted but somewhere along the lines, there were 14:00 in a row, which was odd. How can I sort the table properly?

Comment: Can you add the structure of `table`

Comment: `table[order(table$time),]` assuming that the time column is in Date format (`?as.Date`)

Comment: @EDi good point - if there's no intermediate data.table package usage then the `time` column needs to be accessed by referring to the data frame `table` first.

Comment: Thank you EDi!!!!! You're my savior!! :D Please post that as an asnwer so I can rate it and set as correct answer, thank!

Answer (score 0):

To `order` the columns of a data.frame from left to right, use `do.call`. For example:

```
mtcars[do.call("order",mtcars),]
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If `table` is large (many rows), it will probably be faster to use data tables:

```
library(data.table)
dt     <- data.table(table)
sorted <- setkeyv(dt,colnames(dt))
```